# what's this jquery syntax?

Tags: jquery, parameters, function

I see that quite often in some Jquery plugins

```
    $('#foo').myPlugin({
    foo: 'bar',
            bar: 'foo'
});
```

I'm talking about the {} in the .myPlugin() part. I see quite often anonymous functions like

```
.click(function(){
});
```

but the above syntax looks different

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an object. This notation is used to simulate [named arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) - something that JS can't do natively AFAIK.

It allows for the infinite extension of additional arguments without having to declare them in the function declaration:

```
function myfunc(args)  { }  
vs.
function myfunc(duration, opacity, width, height, speed)  { }
```

and - most importantly - it allows for arbitrary ordering of arguments:

```
{"duration": "0.5",
 "width": 300,
 "speed": 2 }
```

Seeing as many JS developers are not working in the context of an IDE (that would display the expected function parameters using "look-ahead"), that is a very convenient thing, as you don't have to memorize the order of which parameter comes when.

The downside of this is that if there *is* an IDE, it is very hard to provide any "look-ahead" functionality for these fake named arguments, and the arbitrary ordering of arguments can lead to some degree of chaos in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

It's a JavaScript Object literal. It's part of the JavaScript language (not specific to jQuery). JavaScript objects are essentially maps of names and values; the name and the value are separated by a colon, and the pairs are separated from each other by commas. The whole thing is wrapped in a pair of curly braces.

So, if you did something like this:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar', name: 'value' };
```

You could later do something like this:

```
alert(obj.foo); //alerts "bar"
```

or even:

```
alert(obj['foo']); //also alerts "bar"
```

In this case, the object is being passed as a parameter to the myPlugin() function.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a function call where arg is actually map of params.